# Azure storage tables - Entity version history

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to get my head out of relational database design and into Azure Storage Tables for a Big Data pet project I am about to embark upon.

My first question is around recording version histories of my entities.

Say I have a table called Members and I want to be able to see previous versions of the members details could I set the PartitionKey as their member number and then the RowKey of the datetime stamp that it was updated?

Would this be an effective / recommended approach to this version history problem?

Thanks.

Update:
Or would I be better to store the latest entry in the members table and then have a members "history" table that records the changes?

Comment: Will you always be querying this "Members" table of yours for a particular member? Will there be a scenario where you would want to fetch the details about all the members from this table?

Comment: I doubt I would ever want to get a complete collection of members.  I might want to get details of a "set" of members, such as "members I am following", etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take both approaches. Just thinking out loud, here are some of the possible approaches:

**Approach 1: Keeping member information and history in a single table (1)**

The way this would work is you would keep the `PartitionKey` as member's unique identifier and the `RowKey` as the timestamp from when the member's information was updated. Since you would want to get the latest information about the member, I would recommend you keep the `RowKey` in reverse chronological order using something like:

```
var rowKey = (DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString("d20");
```

To get the latest information about a member, you would fetch just one row for a given `PartitionKey` (i.e. member ID). To get complete history about a member, you would just fetch all rows.

One problem with this approach is that you can't fetch current details about any members without knowing their member IDs.

**Approach 2: Keeping member information and history in separate tables**

In this approach you will maintain two tables—one for member information (let's call it `Member`) and other for member history (let's call it `MemberHistory`). The `PartitionKey` in `Member` table could be member ID and row key could be any arbitrary value (or even `null` value). The `PartitionKey` in the `MemberHistory` table would be member ID and the `RowKey` would be the timestamp when the information was updated. Again, you would want to store them in reverse chronological order.

The way this would work is that you always perform an `InsertOrUpdate` (or `InsertOrMerge`) operation on entities in `Members` table, while you would always perform `Insert` operation on entities in `MembersHistory` table.

While this approach is much neater and gives you the capability of extracting current information about all members, the problem you will run into is that you can't take the advantage of the transaction feature in Azure Table Storage since you're dealing with two tables. So it may happen that your main table gets updated but your history table fails to update, thus you have to cover for that scenario as well.

**Approach 3: Keeping member information and history in a single table (2)**

In this approach, for the main record and history record, you would keep the `PartitionKey` as member ID but keep the `RowKey` as empty for the main record and `RowKey` as the timestamp (again in reverse chronological order) for the history tables.

To query a member's current record, you would query something like (pseudo code):

```
PartitionKey == 'Member ID' && RowKey == ''
```

To query a member's history record, you would query something like (pseudo code):

```
PartitionKey == 'Member ID' && RowKey != ''
```

To query all members for their current record, you would query something like (pseudo code):

```
RowKey == ''
```

Please note that the query above will do a full table scan so be prepared for continuation tokens and some performance degradation.

Comment: HI Gaurav, That is a fantastically detailed and laid out answer. Good to see I was on the right track, but it's great to have the different options presented in that way.  I think the third approach will suit my needs the most.

Comment: I wonder if I can automatically create the history entity when an InsertOrUpdate method is called.  I might need to play around with the Insert / Update methods a bit.. but I think it should be possible.

Comment: Afaik you can't. This is something you've to code for yourself.